# Usage of rdf & owl to markup WebGL content

Tags: webgl, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

i have given scene in webGL of a pizza for example. Now i want to make the content in the scene semantic  visible for maschines with a custom owl and rdf for example.

When i make a owl ontologie with protege can i just use this ontology like here
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146898 and instead of linking to
http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/# i link to my own ontology and use my properties, tags etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

WebGL is an API. Any data is outside the scope of WebGL. There is nothing to markup or add any ontology to.

Maybe you're looking for something like [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer gman.
Yeah i already know X3DOM and there already exist some papers about a solution how to map the X3DOM content to a MPEG-7 description.

At the moment iam researching for a way to make webGL rendered content visible for external search engines like google. I think webGL could be a big benefit for the web.
eg.: http://ogreen.special-t.com/en/
The idea is to develope a framework or API maybe based on three.js or another lib to create automaticly a matching ontologie for the scene, to make a semantic visible interface for external resources to the webGL content.